# Incorrect syntax near '455555' - When i try to search on database

Tags: c#, sql, database, syntax

I have a SEARCH field on my form and I have two radionbuttons, one called RG and another called NOME and bascially these are the search criteria : by name or by RG. A search by name works normal but the search for RG is returning an error. Below is the code.

```
                if (rdbPorRG.Checked) // Faz consulta com o RG
                {
                    if (txtPesquisar.Text == "")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Favor escolher um parâmetro de busca \r\n" + "e preencher o campo de pesquisa \r\n" + "para efetuar a consulta.", "Consultar Item", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        txtPesquisar.ReadOnly = true;
                        CmSQL.Remove(0, CmSQL.Length);
                        CmSQL.Append("SELECT * FROM TB_CADASTRO ");
                        CmSQL.Append("WHERE RG = " + Convert.ToInt64(txtPesquisar.Text) + " ");
                        SDR = clsConexao.ExecutarDataReader(CmSQL.ToString());

                        if (!SDR.Read()) // Lê os dados resgatados e exibe para o usuário.
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("RG não encontrado.", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Asterisk); txtPesquisar.Clear(); txtPesquisar.Focus(); txtPesquisar.ReadOnly = false;
                            return;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            DS = clsConexao.ExecutarDataSet("SELECT ID, RG, NOME, ITENS_DOADOS AS 'ITENS DOADOS' FROM TB_CADASTRO WHERE RG " + Convert.ToInt64(txtPesquisar.Text) + " "); // Seleciona TUDO que está na tabela aluno no Banco de Dados.
                            DT = DS.Tables[0]; // Extrai a tabela 0 do DATASET
                            dgvRegistros.DataSource = DT;
                            txtPesquisar.ReadOnly = false;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

Comment: Obligatory "don't build SQL queries by concatenating strings, use prepared statements instead", SQL injection yadiyadiya. Did you bother searching for the error at all?

Comment: probably `FROM TB_CADASTRO WHERE RG `  - missing `=`, but also, use parameters for SQL, not string concat

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like this line

```
DS = clsConexao.ExecutarDataSet("SELECT ID, RG, NOME, ITENS_DOADOS AS 'ITENS DOADOS' FROM TB_CADASTRO WHERE RG " + Convert.ToInt64(txtPesquisar.Text) + " ");
```

is missing an "=" sign on its where clause. Try

```
SELECT ID, RG, NOME, ITENS_DOADOS AS 'ITENS DOADOS' FROM TB_CADASTRO WHERE RG = " + Convert.ToInt64(txtPesquisar.Text) + " "
```

Comment: Thank you , it really was the problem. It is solved. But as falram me to answer this question , I will try to use SQL parameters to prevent SQL Injection .